# How to Check if find returns as null?

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, text

Im working a page thats dynamic and sometimes it has elements and sometimes it does not.

```html
$data2 = $data1->find("tr td");
```

Is there a way I can check if the code below returns null? It works fine when it is found but it throws the error when it is not:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on null in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rs/login.php on line 175

full function code:

```html
  $url = "http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=";
  $link = $url . $name;
  $html = file_get_html($link);

  $data1 = $html->find("div[id=contentHiscores] table tbody",0); 
  $data2 = $data1->find("tr td"); 
  
  $data2 = (!empty($data1)) ? $data1->find("tr td") : null;
  if(empty($data2)){
      echo 'empty';
  }else{
      echo 'do something';
  }
```

Comment: if (empty($data2))
OR
if (null === $data2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the problem in `$data1` variable. When `$data1` is null it throws error.

```
$url = "http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=";
$link = $url . $name;
$html = file_get_html($link);

$data1 = (!empty($html)) ? $html->find("div[id=contentHiscores] table tbody",0) : null; 
$data2 = (!empty($data1)) ? $data1->find("tr td") : null;

if(empty($data2)){
    echo 'empty';
}else{
    echo 'do something';
}
```

Comment: It would echo 'Do something' but it would never echo 'Empty'. Same error thrown. I also added the full link in question in my original post.